# ICSharpCode Decompiler get from TypeReferenceExpression to TypeDeclaration?

Tags: .net, decompiling, icsharpcode, ilspy

I'm using `ICSharpCode.Decompiler.Ast.AstBuilder` (which is used by SharpDevelop, NRefactory and ILSpy under the hood; has taken inspiration from there too) from code to build an abstract syntax tree from a .NET Common Intermediate Language assembly.

```
var assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assemblyPath);
var astBuilder = new AstBuilder(new DecompilerContext(assembly.MainModule));
astBuilder.AddAssembly(assembly);
// astBuilder.SyntaxTree ...
```

The syntax tree contains `TypeReferenceExpression`s whenever a line like `Math.Abs()` is there. How can I retrieve the `TypeDeclaration` of the referenced type when it also exists in the same syntax tree?

The closest I got is `TypeReferenceExpression.Type.ToTypeReference().Resolve()` but this is very heavy to orchestrate, and I already have (I suppose) all the information in the syntax tree. I also tried manual lookup by using namespaces an identifiers but I guess there should be a better way.

Comment: Do you want the `TypeDeclaration` or `TypeDefinition`?  Based on my recollection of those APIs, calling `Resolve()` as in your example produces the definition (metadata), not the declaration (AST node).

Comment: I'd like to access the TypeDeclaration (which is in the same syntax tree). But you're right that Resolve() returns metadata only so that's not really an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SyntaxTree.GetTypes()` to enumerate all decompiled types.  Since that's rather heavy, I'd build up a reference-to-declaration lookup, e.g.:

```
var assembly = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(assemblyPath);
var astBuilder = new AstBuilder(new DecompilerContext(assembly.MainModule));

astBuilder.AddAssembly(assembly);

var ast = astBuilder.SyntaxTree;

var lookup = ast.GetTypes(true)
                .ToDictionary(d => (TypeReference)d.Annotation<TypeDefinition>());
```

You can then fetch the `TypeReference` from your `TypeReferenceExpression` and use it to find the type's declaration in the lookup:

```
TypeReferenceExpression e = /* ... */;
TypeDeclaration declaration;

if (lookup.TryGetValue(e.Type.Annotation<TypeReference>(), out declaration))
    Console.WriteLine(declaration.GetText());  // do whatever
```

Comment: Nice, very clever, thank you! Didn't know about such annotations automatically added to nodes.

Comment: It's worth noting that while this will work fine for types within the same assembly it won't find the type declaration once the referencing code is in a separate assembly (the TypeReference objects will differ). Changing the implementation to use the FullName as the key seems like a solution.

Comment: Interesting.  Using the full, assembly-qualified type name as the key might be the best solution then.  You may need to compute it yourself, though--I don't recall whether `TypeReference` has a specific property to access the assembly-qualified name.

Comment: The FullName property is good enough in this use-case, although not bullet proof.